# How to use QtWebview for Google Maps

Tags: c++, qt, qwebview

Basically I want to use it for googlemaps but at the moment I can't even get it to compile a simple web page.

I'm using the latest version of `Qt` creator but the documentation just seems out of date

i have dragged the widget onto my form and set its url to google.com (just for testing purposes)

and when i hit compile i get loads of unresolved external symbol errors, I don't know what to include to use this I just assumed drag and drop the widget and I'm good to go, however this isn't the case.

Any ideas?

Comment: Seriously no one has anything to suggest even?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: For Qt 4.x, this is what you do:

Go into your .pro file and include the right module for QtWebKit.

http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtWebKit

> QT += webkit

And here is an example you can find in the welcome pages of Qt Creator if you want more:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/webkit-fancybrowser.html

Good luck; hope that helps.  And btw, I just tested it with Google Maps, and it renders fine with Qt 4.8.4 on Win 7.

EDIT: For Qt 5.x+, this is what you do:

> QT += webkitwidgets

Like it shows in the .pro file of any of the examples here:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwebkitexamples/webkitwidgets-browser-browser-pro.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwebkitexamples/qtwebkitexamples-index.html

And you may want to consider also adding the `network` module in the pro file, too.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so iv seen the `QT +=webkit` solution all over the place which for the record doesnt work if you have just dragged a dropped a webview into a widget using qt designer.

the solution i finally found that worked was

```
QT+=webkitwidgets
```

all working now thought id answer my own question after solving it to help anyone else who might be having the same problem